# Dynamically imported modules without relative paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a Symfony application that uses React to build the front-end. As of our last release the build size of the react app has become too large and actually runs out of memory on the server trying to compile. I have been attempting to implement code splitting and have the initial page load to be much more efficient. I am running into a problem with the routes.

My router is defined similar to this.

```html
import React from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import DelayedLoading from 'components/DelayedLoading';
export default [
  component: Loadable({loader: () => import('containers/Page'), loading: DelayedLoading}),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Loadable({loader: () => import('containers/MainPage'), loading: DelayedLoading}),
    },
    {
      path: '/foo/bar',
      component: Loadable({loader: () => import('containers/FooBarPage'), loading: DelayedLoading}),
    },
  ]
];
```

In my webpack config I have defined

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'web'),
    filename: 'react/js/[name].js',
  },
}
```

Any time a path is two or more deep then the chunks try to load from the wrong directory. For example, the `foo/bar` route above will try to load chunks at `foo/react/js/___.js`, but chunks loaded from the `/` route, or any route that is just one deep will correctly load from `react/js/___.js`.

How can I get all of the chunks to load from `react/js`?

Comment: Try changing the `path` property to `path.resolve(__dirname, 'web/react/js')` and the `filename` property to `[name].js`. You shouldn't be including a path in the `filename` property.

Comment: When the assets are built for production they are placed in `${output.path}/${output.filename}`. In my case `web/react/js/` is the directory that these assets need to be placed on the filesystem so they can be served. What this led me to was webpack always trying to load the resources directly from `/{resource}.js`. By add an additional property `publicPath: '/react/js'` I was able to get webpack to spit out the files to the `web/react/js/` directory and serve them from `/react/js/` without prefixing directory paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was arrived at in the discussion of the question, but I'm putting the final answer here in case someone comes across this question and is looking for the accepted answer, not reading the comments. Big thanks to @Adam for pushing me in the right direction.

I had to update `output` configuration as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'web/react/js'),
    publicPath: '/react/js',
    filename: '[name].js',
  }
}
```

With this configuration compiling the code will output to the `web/react/js/` directory, but code from the web will be served from `/react/js/`. Webpack will not automatically prefix the path to server the JS code from based on the route of the page trying to access it.

Answer (score 0):

I avoid these issues by using [webpack resolve](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) instead

Comment: I don't think there are options in webpack.resolve to address where the assets are compiled.